# Remove the attribute and provide your own private lock object. - Code Dx

Tags: vb.net

Reported by Gendarme: Gendarme / Concurrency / Do Not Use Method Impl Options Synchronized [CWE-412]

Location: Pages/ProfileCreation.aspx.vb

This method is decorated with [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]. Remove the attribute and provide
your own private lock object.

Comment: Just copying an error message is not sufficient.  Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).